# Can't install Mercure for Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, mercure

I tried to follow the documentation for mercure and symfony found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html#installing-the-symfony-component) but always encounter an error.

The first part :

```
>composer require mercure
```

Works with no issue but as soon as I try to do the second one, I always get the same error.

The second action:

```
> mercure --jwt-key='!ChangeMe!' --addr='localhost:3000' --allow-anonymous --cors-allowed-origins='*'
```

The error :

```
time="2020-12-08T17:35:14+01:00" level=info msg="Mercure started" addr="'localhost:3000'" protocol=http
time="2020-12-08T17:35:14+01:00" level=fatal msg="listen tcp: lookup tcp/3000': getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found."
```

I have never used Mercure before so I have no idea what to do... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work on windows, you must create a bat file like this (mercureScript.bat) :

```
set JWT_KEY=!ChangeMe!
set ADDR=localhost:3000
set ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
set CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
.\mercure.exe
```

And just run : `.\mercureScript.bat`

Hoping it serves you !